# How to expand context based on whitespace in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know I can do `Expand Select` to increase the selection scope, but I'm wondering if there is a way to select based on whitespace. I would like to select lines 2-9 with a shortcut:

```
line1

line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9

line10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating an extension for this: [Select Paragraph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nachocab.select-paragraph)